# What does Model::unguard() do in the database seeder file from Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to find out what is the purpose of `Model::unguard();` and `Model::reguard();` in the `DatabaseSeeder.php` file that ships with Laravel. I have gone through the seeding documentation at laravel's site and googled but in vain.

So what is the purpose of `Model::unguard();`? Assuming `Model::reguard();` is just the opposite.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`Model::unguard()` does temporarily disable the mass assignment protection of the model, so you can seed all model properties.

Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment for more information about mass assignment in Eloquent.

Answer (score 24):

Take for example the currency table
Migration file

```
    $table->double('rate');
    $table->boolean('is_default')->default(false);
```

If your Currency Model file, the only fillables are

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'rate',
    ]
```

`is_default` can never be set by mass assignment. For example

```
Currency::create([
   'rate' => 5.6,
   'is_default' => true
])
```

will return a currency with

```
'rate' => 5.6
'is_default' => false
```

But you can mass assign the field using unguard and reguard as follows

```
Model::unguard()
Currency::create([
   'rate' => 5.6,
   'is_default' => true
])
Model::reguard()
```

Then your model will be created with

```
'rate' => 5.6
'is_default' => true
```

Comment: thumbs up for a much more detailed explanation than the accepted one